# sum of multiple fields in group by clause and create single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this.

```
Id Name Test Subject   Marks
----------------------------
1  Alex 1    Maths     40
1  Alex 2    Maths     80
1  Alex 1    Sociology 55
1  Alex 2    Sociology 70
1  Alex 3    Sociology 60
2  Mark 1    Maths     30
2  Mark 2    Maths     60
2  Mark 1    Sociology 40
2  Mark 2    Sociology 50
2  Mark 3    Sociology 30
```

What I need is a group by on Id, Name, Subject and sum(Marks) in a single row, to give a result like:

```
Id Name Maths Sociology
-----------------------
1  Alex 120   185
2  Mark 90    120
```

I can get this as:

```
Id Name Marks
--------------
1  Alex  120
2  Mark   90
```

or:

```
Id Name  Marks
-------------
1  Alex  185
2  Mark  120
```

I tried multiple options but I'm getting multiple rows for each ID.

The query below is not working:

```
select 
    Id, Name, Sum(Marks) where Subject = 'Maths' as Maths,Sum(Marks ) where Subject = 'Sociology' as Sociology
from 
    Table
group by 
    Id, Name;
```

I get this error:

> "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:66 missing EOF at 'as' near ''Maths''

Comment: You should use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to effectively filter the values going into your `sum`:

```
select Id
      ,Name
      ,sum(case when Subject = 'Maths' then Marks else 0 end) as Maths
      ,sum(case when Subject = 'Sociology' then Marks else 0 end) as Sociology
from Table
group by Id
        ,Name;
```

If you are looking to do this across a lot of different `subject` values however, you will need to look at using `pivot`:

```
select Id
      ,[Name]
      ,[Maths]
      ,[Sociology]
from (select Id, [Name], [Subject], Marks from @t) as t
pivot(sum(Marks)
      for [Subject] in(Maths,Sociology)
    ) as p;
```

Comment: doesn't give the output as OP suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `PIVOT`. Try :

```
create table #tbl(Id int, Name varchar(20), Test int, Subject varchar(20), Marks int)
insert into #tbl values
(1,'Alex',1,'Maths', 40    ),
(1,'Alex',2,'Maths', 80    ),
(1,'Alex',1,'Sociology', 55),
(1,'Alex',2,'Sociology', 70),
(1,'Alex',3,'Sociology', 60),
(2,'Mark',1,'Maths', 30    ),
(2,'Mark',2,'Maths', 60    ),
(2,'Mark',1,'Sociology', 40),
(2,'Mark',2,'Sociology', 50),
(2,'Mark',3,'Sociology', 30)

--select * from #tbl

SELECT ID,Name,Maths,Sociology
FROM(
    SELECT ID, Name, Subject, Marks
    FROM #tbl
    ) tbl
PIVOT(
    SUM(Marks) FOR Subject IN (Maths, Sociology)
) piv
```

output:

```
ID          Name  Maths       Sociology
----------- ---- ------------ -----------
1           Alex  120         185
2           Mark  90          120
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `PIVOT` operator:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,Name
    ,Maths
    ,Sociology
FROM(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Name
        ,Subject
        ,Marks
    FROM your_table
) tbl
PIVOT(
    SUM(Marks) FOR Subject IN (Maths, Sociology)
) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query :

```
select id,name,maths_marks,sociology_marks
from
(select id,name,test,subject,marks
from table)
pivot(sum(marks) for subject in ('Maths' as Maths_marks,'Sociology' as Sociology_marks);
```